# Data Migration - SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2017

I have a problem with a data migration. I will try to give all the information to help me solve this situation. A little of history:

In 2005 an internal website was developed to help manage its business. Due to the latency and change of business rules a developer was hired in 2019 to put "order in the house" (me). When I got the website I was not given the source code, without thinking twice I performed a platform from scratch in C#. All right here, everything was a success. The problem then arose in data migration.

The most important thing to keep, was the files (pdf, .xsd, etc). I then picked up the data from SQL Server 2005 (old website) to SQL Server 2017 (new website).
The content of the files on the old website was in the data type of 'IMAGE' and after research I found it better to put in the new website as 'VARBINARY'.
With the data all migrated, on the new website when I have downloaded the file I get the following error message:

> Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'file_name' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)

I do not know if it helps but for example, if I insert a file normally on the website its download works correctly. The field is that it behaves differently (the first was the one inserted by the website and the others came from the migration).

This is a print screen of database:

http://prntscr.com/mwilex

Does anyone know why the error? Has anyone ever come across a similar situation?

Bst: I run a query [**SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')**] and the output of the two Databases are the same, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Comment: "without thinking twice I performed a platform from scratch in C#" - You . Maybe that was your first error. To rebuild a system from scratch without doing an analysis of existing data might be just that.

Comment: Please post your messages [as text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) [in your question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Posting pictures of errors on external sites does no one any good.

Comment: If you're getting an error on the new downloads but not the old downloads, then [compare them](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/diff-tools-windows/).

Comment: @user23332, I did not have access to the source code, I think it's too late for that now.
 ||

Dour High Arch, it's a print screen for u understand.. What is the purpose of comparing?

Comment: @DourHighArch, ^ message above.

Comment: @DourHighArch I already compare the output for old and new database and it's equal